# What is the effect of moving a propeller closer to a wing?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, propeller-aircraft

Does it improve efficiency?

What if the wing is just a plate? Certainly increasing plate thickness will decrease efficiency.

Comment: What do you mean closer to a wing?  Along which axis? (ie moving a prop from nose to wing, or moving a prop mounted in front of a wing, back towards the wing, or moving a pusher prop forward to be close to the rear of the wing)

Comment: @tmptplayer in front of a wing, moving closer to the wing as in reducing the distance between the prop blade and the leading edge of the wing